# How can i get the current log file name on runtime from tinylog

Tags: tinylog

i am using tinylog 2 and i want to load the current log file content to show it in my gui.
My tinylog.properties looks something like this:

```
writer=rolling file
writer.file=project_{date: yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

So my problem is: How can i get the current filename of the logger file ?
i can resolve it with hard coded java String formatter, but when someone change the properties file it doesn't fit.
Is there a way to get the current resolved logfile name from Tinylog?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

tinylog 2 does not provide any specific API for receiving the file name. However, feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_request.md&title=) on GitHub. As the main contributor of tinylog, I could imagine to implement such feature for tinylog 2 or 3. Especially, I'm thinking about a listener that could automatically inform you about a rollover event and provide the new file name.

Comment: Thanks, i have submit a feature request